# C++ Pointers and Functions with no return - need to recall the output as a pointer

Tags: c++

> Write a C++ code that calls the function add_three() that takes three float numbers and add them together, the function should not return anything, and the output variable should be passed as an input to the function. Note: the number of argument is four.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void add_three(float, float *);

int main() 
{
  float s,r;
  float a[3];
  add_three(a[3], &r); //use of undeclared identifier 'a'

  cout<< "The sum is " << s; //use of undeclared identifier 's'

  return 0;
}

void add_three(float a[3], float *s)
{
  float r = 0;
  
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      cin >> a[i];
      r = r + a[i]; //invalid operands to binary expression ('float *' and 'float')
    }
  *s = &r;
  
}
```

Errors:

```
assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'float *'; remove &
  *s = &r;
```

I am stuck and can't understand what I am doing wrong (BTW, I am a complete novice).

Comment: as far as I understood it the prototype should like `void add_three(float,float,float,float&)` then you pass the first three by value and the fourth you pass as a reference (or pointer if you prefer) where the result will be placed. So first get the values from the user, then call the function and then present the result.

Comment: `*s = &r;` is nonsense. It should be `*s = r;` . And in `main`, besides the out-of-range improper use of `a[3]`, the variable `r` is what is being used to reap the sum. Therefore printing `s` is also useless (and in fact, in `main` the variable `s` itself is completely useless and should just be removed entirely).

Comment: Deleted my answer because the other one is much more thorough, but its worth noting your exact error ( `use of undeclared identifier 'a'`) was because a[3] was off the end of the array.

Comment: The compiler is entirely right in this case: `remove &`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that you attempt to pass a single `float` value to the function, which is declared to take a single `float` value.

Then you create an *overload* of that function, which takes a *pointer* to a `float` value. The function declaration

```
void add_three(float, float*);
```

is different from

```
void add_three(float*, float*);
```

You also make it worse by passing the *fourth* element from your three-element array.

Then there's the assignment

```
*s = &r;
```

It tries to assign the pointer to the variable `r` (the type of the expression `&r` is `float*`) to the floating-point value `*s`.

You probably want

```
*s = r;
```

Or better yet, use proper *references* to pass `s` by reference:

```
// First argument: Pass a pointer to the first element of the array
// Second argument: Pass a reference to the variable
void add_three(float* a, float& s);
```

Call as:

```
float a[3];
float s;
add_three(a, s);
```

---

As an alternative you could *return* the sum instead of passing references. This is actually the method I recommend:

```
// First argument: Pointer to the first element of your array
// Returns: The sum of all three elements
float add_three(float* a);
```

Call as:

```
float a[3];
float s = add_three(a);
```

Or considering that you don't actually use `a` in the `main` function, you could skip passing it as an argument. In fact, you don't need an array at all:

```
float add_three()
{
    float input, sum = 0;  // Initialize sum to zero

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        // Note: Really need some error checking and validation here
        std::cin >> input;
        sum += input;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Simply call as:

```
float s = add_three();
```

Even if you *must* use arguments to "return" the value, you can do it without the array.